# JObject parser stops executing without giving any output or error

Tags: c#, jquery, json, parsing, json.net

I am trying to parse a JSON result from webapi with this code:

```
var pemail = "tonys@gmail.com";
var _pid = GetRequest(Global.token, apiBaseUri, apiGetPerson +"?pemail="+ pemail).Result;
var pid = JObject.Parse(_pid).GetValue("perso_nid").ToString();
MessageBox.Show(pid);
```

When I run this, it just finishes the execution without any output or error.

During the debug `var _pid` gets the correct value

```
[{"person_id":1141,
"person_fname":"Tony",
"person_lname":"Stark",
"person_initials":"IM",
"person_mono":"1234567890",
"person_pemail":"tonys@gmail.com",
"status":"0",
"db_tstamp":"2020-01-08T22:03:08.9659938"}]
```

But on next line it just stops execution and doesn't go to next line. No output or error.

Comment: The JSON shown at the end of your question is an array containing an object, not an object.  To parse it an extract the value of `person_id` from the first array entry, use `JToken.Parse(_pid).SelectToken("[0].person_id")?.ToString()`.

Comment: @dbc oh Yes. It resolved. Thanks man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON shown in your question is an array containing an object, not an object.  To parse it and extract the value of `person_id` from the first array entry, use [`JToken.Parse()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Parse.htm) with [`SelectToken()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectToken.htm):

```
var pid = JToken.Parse(_pid).SelectToken("[0].person_id")?.ToString();
```

Or, use [`JArray.Parse()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray_Parse.htm) to enforce that the root value really is an array:

```
var pid = JArray.Parse(_pid)[0]?["person_id"]?.ToString();
```

Note that the JSON property name is **`"person_id"`** not `"perso_nid"`; be sure to use the correct name in your code.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/P3EMsX).